# How to call a thread from another thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, graphics

I want to know how can I call a thread from another thread in C# Windows Form Application. I am developing the UI using TCP/IP communication. In my program, I send the data from Console application (client) to Windows Form Application(server) after receiving the data I want to plot it at UI on Picture Box.

I have created the two threads on the server first thread is the Listener thread (which listens to the client socket) and the second thread is the Handler thread (which handles data received from the client socket) I want to create the graphics plotting thread from the handler thread.

Currently, I am doing the graphics plotting within the handler thread, but I want to do it in a separate thread.  please guide me how can I do it?

Comment: what object types are 'path' and 'g'?

Comment: "path" does continuous plot  and "g" does point plotting

Comment: What do you mean call a thread from another thread? Is the thread already running and you want to pass data to it?

Comment: the handler thread is already running and in this shared block the graphic plotting did within this thread, but I want to create a new thread for graphic plotting.. the data which is read and processed in a handler thread is to plot in an another thread, I want to know how can I create a thread for plotting the "data"?

Answer (score 0):

There's a million ways to skin this cat, but here's my suggestion for the simplest approach.  I assume you know how to create threads, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace foo
{
    class Packet
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
        public double z;
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        Queue<Packet> qp;

        public Class1()
        {
            qp = new Queue<Packet>();
        }

        public void SendData(Packet p)
        {
            // prevent reader from accessing while we insert
            lock (qp)
            {
                qp.Enqueue(p);
            }
        }

        public void ProcessIncomingPackets()
        {
            Packet p;

            // or until we decide to stop
            while (true)
            {
                p = null;

                // prevent the writer from adding while we're reading and maybe removing an item
                lock (qp)
                {
                    if (0 < qp.Count)
                    {
                        p = qp.Dequeue();
                    }
                }

                // with lock released, do something if we have a packet
                if (null != p)
                {
                    // graph, etc.
                }

                // spin faster for better responsiveness and more wasted CPU
                Thread.Sleep(100); // milliseconds
            }
        }

    } // Class 1
} // namespace
```

There's also a million ways to optimize this, but also create really nasty bugs. 
 So I suggest you do some reading on synchronization, threads, data structures for message passing, and those specific to C#.  A good computer science book on generic sync/threads generally provides a critical foundation for understanding the various platform/language specific implementations you'll encounter over the years.  Testing any multithreaded code in tight loops is a good idea, especially if you can't prove the correctness of your synchronization directly.